# How substring method works in C

Tags: c, algorithm, substring

How sub string method works in C?

What is the algorithm behind sub string method in C?

Does it use KMP Algorithm..?

Suggest me a way or provide me the source code?

Comment: There's no one canonical C library implementation, and thus no one canonical algorithm. Moreover, `substring()` is not a standard C library call.

Comment: 1. What "substring method"? 2. There are no "methods" in C. 3. The algorithm used by standard C library functions is implementation-defined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you tell me if it is not for C then how we use this in our C programs, somewhere it may be defined?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Implementation defined means?

Comment: @anks, `strstr()` is the standard C library's substring call. There is no `substring()` call, and I don't know why you keep claiming there is one. It's "implementation defined" meaning that any C library can implement `strstr()` however it wants to; the standard does not specify an algorithm.

Comment: @anks, ...generally speaking, different C libraries use different algorithms depending on their goals. For instance, the GNU C library cares more about being fast than being small, so it tends to use complex, highly optimized algorithms; dietlibc cares most about size and gives almost no attention at all to performance; musl uses the fastest algorithms it can while still being small and correct; etc... and that's not even getting into proprietary libc implementations. There's not just one libc, so there's not just one algorithm used for any given function.

Answer (score 1):

The method `strstr` is guaranteed to be linear but I don't think three standard specifies any particular algorithm to be used.  However all improvements I've seen in different compilers use KMP.

Comment: @Strandjev Can you put some light on "substr"?

Comment: Eh? According to http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html, both glibc and musl use Crochemore's two-way algorithm, not KMP.

Comment: @anks I am referring to strstr in my answer